# AS400 Nagios Plugin java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "01 % S"

Tags: java, exception, ibm-midrange, nagios, network-monitoring

I am using the AS400 Nagios Plugin in order to manage AS400 servers. For one server I get the following return (Exception):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "01      % S"
```

**Full return:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "01      % S"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
        at check_as400.parseWrkSysSts(check_as400.java:1048)
        at check_as400.parse(check_as400.java:626)
        at check_as400.main(check_as400.java:470)
```

**Command:**

```
./check_as400 -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -v JOBS -w 21000 -c 23000
```

I already found a similar problem and solution in the Nagios Exchange Forum but without access or knowledge regarding AS400 I do not have any idea what to do:

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/IBM/Check_as400/details (see Owner's reply).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:** Additional output with the -d Option

```
Establishing connection to server...done.
Logging in...
  waiting for screen...
    waiting for token IBM CORP...
    token received.
  sending login information for QPGMR...
  waiting for login to process...
    waiting for token ===>...
      responding to allocated to another job message...
    token received.
Login completed.
Sending command (0)...
    waiting for token ===>...
    token received.
Command sent.
Parsing results...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input st                                                                                                                                                                     ring: "01      % S"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatEx                                                                                                                                                                     ception.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
        at check_as400.parseWrkSysSts(check_as400.java:1048)
        at check_as400.parse(check_as400.java:626)
        at check_as400.main(check_as400.java:470)
```

Comment: Can you edit your command to be    ./check_as400 -d -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -v JOBS -w 21000 -c 23000    (note the -d, this outputs exactly what's happening on your connection)

Comment: Can you use an uppercase D? That will give full output including the screen-scrapes performed by check_as400. Probably worth piping the output too:    ./check_as400 -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -D -v JOBS -w 21000 -c 23000 > as400.log

Comment: and obviously obscure anything personal in the log :)

Comment: I discovered the error via "D"-option - the script greps the screen output and parses it and tries to find the value using a grep for a certain amout of ":"-signs (see findToken function). The problem is that an older version have additionals ":" so the result is another position then the expected one. Customer tries to update the system (< V6R1).

Comment: You can amend the amount of ":" that it's counting through, on line 811 of the file check_as400.java you'll see "start=findToken(buffer,":",11)+1;" - Change the 11 to the value that you require and recompile the java code (using javac I think) and it'll grep properly.

Comment: Thanks to @WillRyan:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WillRyan: The Problem is that the server which causes the exceptions had an older version of AS400 (< V6R1). Therefor the ":"-signs which greps the wanted information did not correctly match.